# Including File From Another Directory With Same Filename

Tags: php

I'm trying to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to get the filename but I notice that it include also the path information.  How do I return only the value of the filename?
Right now I'm returning `/web/dir/filename.php` when I just want to return `filename.php`

After I'm able to return the correct syntax, how do I move up a couple directories and also target the `filename.php` file in another folder?

Right now I have:

```
<?php
include ("../../web/dir/".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function `basename(__FILE__)`